# Impossible to SSH to EC2 instance and unable to place ECS task

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, amazon-ecs, terraform-provider-aws

Given the following `terraform.tf` file:

```
provider "aws" {
  profile = "default"
  region = "us-east-1"
}


locals {
  vpc_name = "some-vpc-name"
  dev_vpn_source = "*.*.*.*/32"  # Insted of * I have a CIDR block of our VPN here
}

resource "aws_vpc" "vpc" {
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"
  enable_dns_hostnames = true
  tags = {
    Name: local.vpc_name
  }
}


resource "aws_subnet" "a" {
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/17"
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc.id
  tags = {
    Name: "${local.vpc_name}-a"
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "b" {
  cidr_block = "10.0.128.0/17"
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc.id
  tags = {
    Name: "${local.vpc_name}-b"
  }
}

resource "aws_security_group" "ssh" {
  name = "${local.vpc_name}-ssh"
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc.id
  tags = {
    Name: "${local.vpc_name}-ssh"
  }
}


resource "aws_security_group_rule" "ingress-ssh" {
  from_port = 22
  protocol = "ssh"
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.ssh.id
  to_port = 22
  type = "ingress"
  cidr_blocks = [local.dev_vpn_source]
  description = "SSH access for developer"
}


resource "aws_security_group" "outbound" {
  name = "${local.vpc_name}-outbound"
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.vpc.id
  tags = {
    Name: "${local.vpc_name}-outbound"
  }
}


resource "aws_security_group_rule" "egress" {
  from_port = 0
  protocol = "all"
  security_group_id = aws_security_group.outbound.id
  to_port = 65535
  type = "egress"
  cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  description = "All outbound allowed"
}

module "ecs-clusters" {
  source = "./ecs-clusters/"
  subnets = [aws_subnet.a, aws_subnet.b]
  vpc_name = local.vpc_name
  security_groups = [aws_security_group.ssh, aws_security_group.outbound]
}
```

And the following `ecs-clusters/ecs-cluster.tf` file:

```
variable "vpc_name" {
  type = string
}

variable "subnets" {
  type = list(object({
    id: string
  }))
}

variable "security_groups" {
  type = list(object({
    id: string
  }))
}


data "aws_ami" "amazon_linux_ecs" {
  most_recent = true
  owners = ["amazon"]
  filter {
    name   = "name"
    values = ["amzn2-ami-ecs*"]
  }
}

resource "aws_iam_instance_profile" "ecs-launch-profile" {
  name = "${var.vpc_name}-ecs"
  role = "ecsInstanceRole"
}

resource "aws_launch_template" "ecs" {
  name          = "${var.vpc_name}-ecs"
  image_id      = data.aws_ami.amazon_linux_ecs.id
  instance_type = "r5.4xlarge"
  key_name = "some-ssh-key-name"
  iam_instance_profile {
    name = "${var.vpc_name}-ecs"
  }
  block_device_mappings {
    device_name = "/dev/xvda"
    ebs {
      volume_type = "gp3"
      volume_size = 1024
      delete_on_termination = false
    }
  }
  network_interfaces {
    associate_public_ip_address = true
    subnet_id = var.subnets[0].id
    security_groups = var.security_groups[*].id
  }
  update_default_version = true
}

resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "ecs-autoscaling_group" {
  name = "${var.vpc_name}-ecs"
  vpc_zone_identifier = [for subnet in var.subnets: subnet.id]
  desired_capacity   = 1
  max_size           = 1
  min_size           = 1
  protect_from_scale_in = true
  launch_template {
    id = aws_launch_template.ecs.id
    version = aws_launch_template.ecs.latest_version
  }
  tag {
    key = "Name"
    propagate_at_launch = true
    value = "${var.vpc_name}-ecs"
  }
  depends_on = [aws_launch_template.ecs]
}

resource "aws_ecs_capacity_provider" "ecs-capacity-provider" {
  name = var.vpc_name

  auto_scaling_group_provider {
    auto_scaling_group_arn         = aws_autoscaling_group.ecs-autoscaling_group.arn
    managed_termination_protection = "ENABLED"

    managed_scaling {
      maximum_scaling_step_size = 1
      minimum_scaling_step_size = 1
      status                    = "ENABLED"
      target_capacity           = 1
    }
  }
  depends_on = [aws_autoscaling_group.ecs-autoscaling_group]
}


resource "aws_ecs_cluster" "ecs-cluster" {
  name = var.vpc_name
  capacity_providers = [aws_ecs_capacity_provider.ecs-capacity-provider.name]
  depends_on = [aws_ecs_capacity_provider.ecs-capacity-provider]
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "ecs-execution" {
  name = "${var.vpc_name}-ecs-execution"
  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
 "Version": "2012-10-17",
 "Statement": [
   {
     "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
     "Principal": {
       "Service": "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"
     },
     "Effect": "Allow",
     "Sid": ""
   }
 ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_role" "ecs" {
  name = "${var.vpc_name}-ecs"

  assume_role_policy = <<EOF
{
 "Version": "2012-10-17",
 "Statement": [
   {
     "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
     "Principal": {
       "Service": "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"
     },
     "Effect": "Allow",
     "Sid": ""
   }
 ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "execution-role" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.ecs-execution.name
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy"
}

resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "role" {
  role       = aws_iam_role.ecs.name
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3FullAccess"
}
```

I'm facing two problems:

- I can't SSH into EC2 instance created by the autoscaling group, despite the fact that I'm using the same SSH key and VPN to access other EC2 instances. My VPN client config includes route to the target machine via VPN gateway.
- I can't execute task on the ESC cluster. The task gets stuck in provisioning status and then fails with "Unable to run task". The task is configured to use 1 GB of RAM and 1 vCPU.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So you have some private VPC without internet access? How do you ensure that your instances for ECS can download images from ECR or communicate with ECS service?

Comment: @Marcin thanks for the reply. Right, in the meantime I realized that I need internet gateway and route table. I can ssh into machine now. From ecs agent log I can see that it's still unable to authenticate with the ecs cluster because of missing providers. I guess some policy is missing.

Comment: I don't see how do you specify cluster name in your container instances? Usually it is done using user_data.

Comment: @Marcin that is your second correct hint and again I've put user_data in place in the meantime and everything works now. Thanks. Feel free to turn your comments into an answer, so I can upvote and accept, if you care.

Comment: Thanks. Answer added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

There were **two issues** with the original setup:

1. Lack of **connectivity** to ECS and ECR services, which was solved by enabling internet access in the VPC. It is also possible to use VPC interface endpoints for ECS, ECR and S3, if the internet access is not desired.
2. Container instances did not **register** with ECS. This was fixed by  using `user_data` to [bootstrap ECS instances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/bootstrap_container_instance.html) so that they can register with the ECS cluster.